# What are $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ here in this heat equation problem?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, heat-equation

> **Question:** What is $f(x)$ and what is $f(y)$?

---

You are given (no need to check) that the function $G(x-y,t)$ defined by

$$G(x-y,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi c^2 t}}e^{-(x-y)^2/4c^2t}$$

satisfies the $1$-D heat equation

$$G_t(x-y,t)=c^2 G_{xx}(x-y,t), -\infty \lt x \lt \infty, t\gt 0$$
Show that $u(x,t)$ defined by 
$$u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty G(x-y,t)f(y) dy$$

also satisfies the $1$-D heat equation as well as the initial condition
$$\lim \limits_{t\to 0^+} u(x,t)=f(x)$$

---

I think perhaps $f(y)$ isn't relevant, since:
$$u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty G(x-y,t)f(y) dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 0f(y)\,dy=0$$
And therefore this integral does satisfy the heat equation.

Perhaps for $f(x)$ they are saying that for $u(x,t)=F(x)G(t)$ we have $u(x,0)=F(x)$ e.g. $G(0)=1$. I am not totally sure.

Comment: @Fektmasa This is from a past exam. Semester 2, 2013

Comment: It can be verified by taking derivatives of $G$. Oh, and $f(x)$ is your initial data.... $f(y)$ is your initial data with the variable $y$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @Jeb I can't see where I am given this initial data $f(x)$? Everything you see above, is what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the one dimensional heat equation
$$  \left \{ \begin{array}{cc}  u_t - c^2 u_{xx} = 0 \\ u(x,0) = f(x) \end{array} \right. $$
It can be shown by direct verification that
$$u(x,t) = G * f $$
where $*$ is the convolution operator, i.e. what you have written above. $f(x)$ is the initial data specified. Why does this come about? If you take a Fourier transform and solve the 1st order equation, you'll obtain
$$ \hat u( \xi ,t) = \hat f ( \xi ) \hat G (\xi,t) $$
This is why it's nice to specify the time $t=0$ with something.

Comment: I see, thank you, this clears up the problems :). I should be fine from here